# Hello!Need help asap with Ubuntu 18.10 and iPhone 8 Plus

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to copy all my photos from the iPhone 8 Plus to my Ubuntu 18.10 laptop?Thanks in advance

Comment: Just one classic attempt with the lighting cable and got the lockdown error :(.

Comment: Using Google Drive app on both of your Ubuntu and iPhone to access or download your photos among of them may be a good idea.

Comment: How about iPhone --> iCloud --> Browser on Ubuntu?

Comment: The main problem in iCloud lately is that it doesn t let you select all you need to pick a pic one at a time:(

Answer (score 2):

This really is trivial to find out by using that Internet thingy.  For example, [addictivetips](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/access-photos-videos-on-your-iphone-on-linux/)  suggests installing iFuse on Ubuntu.   Or, [beebom](https://beebom.com/how-use-iphone-with-linux/) has instructions on how to use OwnCloud and XAMPP.

Comment: Yes,unfortunately it gets really frustrating with Apple sometimes.Can"t wait to go back on Android to be honest.Anyway thanks a lot guys.The Google Drive trick might do the work.I am backing up Photos on it at the moment.